# weak entity depending on either one of two other entity

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, erd

Consider that we have employee as an entity and it's family member as a weak entity. We want to have family members health record. so we add another weak entity "Health Record". The ER diagram would look like this: ( each entity have some attributes that I didn't specify them)

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Z4J.png)

everything is ok now. but suppose that we want to save health record for each employee too. how the ER diagram would be in this situation. Health Record is still a weak entity and it exists with an employee or a family member. If we change the ER Diagram like the image below then it is dependent on both family member and Employee but the existence of one of them(Employee or Family member is enough for the existence of Health Record):

[Wrong ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLU27.png)

Comment: I am sorry if i am wrong , but you want to achieve a database design which works for example: if an EMPLOYEE has a FAMILY MEMBER and if FAMILY MEMBER has a health record? let me know if thats the situation i can provide you with a database design for that.

Comment: Yes but the employee also have a health record

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i understand your question & i have designed a database for you to save all the information relationship-wise.

So we will need 3 tables:

1. **Employees** - Stores all personal information about employees.
2. **FamilyMembers** - Stores all personal information about employee's family members.
3. **HealthRecords** - Stores all healt records of employees & familymembers.

**Employees table design**

```
Columns
-- ---- ----- --- ----- -------- -------- ----- ---------- -------------------
id name email age phone address1 address2 state graduation total_familymembers Etc...
-- ---- ----- --- ----- -------- -------- ----- ---------- -------------------
```

**FamilyMembers table design**

```
Columns
-- ----------- ---- ----- --- ----- --- -------------- 
id employee_id name email age phone sex marital_status Etc...
-- ----------- ---- ----- --- ----- --- --------------
```

**HealthRecords table design**

```
Columns
-- ----------- --------- ------ ------ --- --------- ----------------- ----------
id person_type person_id height weight sex eye_color bodyfatpercentage teethcolor Etc...
-- ----------- --------- ------ ------ --- --------- ----------------- ----------
```

Now you must have understood how Employees table and FamilyMembers table are related , with column id of Employees and column employee_id of FamilyMembers.

Lets come to HealthRecords table , so basically you store all health record information here but if its of a employee you insert "employee" in person_type column & id of the employee in person_id column & if its of a family member you insert "family member" in person_type column & id of the family member in person_id column.

Now first you get all the employees and check the column **total_familymembers** is 0 or not. if its 0 that means you don't have to check for its family members in the FamilyMembers table but if its more than 0 then you get all the rows from FamilyMembers table which have employee_id matching to the employee & after everything you query all the health records from HealthRecords table, for employee you search for person_type ("employee") and person_id (Employee's id) & for FamilyMember you search for person_type ("family member") and person_id (Family member's id).

Make sure to increase the value of **total_familymembers** column every time you insert a new record of family member for the employee so you have the count in the column.

Let me know if this helps you and if i didn't understand something , pardon me and let me know what it is.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your complete answer but my question was about the diagram. (the answer I am expecting is something like the images I attached)  we haven't learned these things yet!

Comment: in that case i think if you design your database as i told you in the answer & use the relationships of the diagram which you say is wrong. the wrong er diagram you provided is actually right on the basis of relationships.